# Simple clarification on Perkins Particle Astrophysics

Tags: particle-physics, mass-energy

In the beginning of Perkins' Particle Astrophysics (pg 13) book he states:

> "Wavy, curly, or broken lines run between the vertices where the exchange
>   interactions take place, and they represent the mediating bosons, which are
>   virtual particles, that is, they carry energy and momentum such that the mass
>   does not correspond to that of the free particle.To understand this, consider, for example, an electron of total energy E, momentum p, and mass m being scattered as another electron absorbs the exchanged photon. The relativistic relation between E, p, and m is given in (1.1), which in units c = 1 is
>
> $E^2 -p^2=0$
>
> If the electron emits a photon of energy $\Delta$E and momentum $\Delta$p then
>
> $E\Delta E-p\Delta p = 0$
>
> so that the mass of the exchanged photon is
>
> $\Delta m^2 = \Delta E^2 -\Delta p^2 = -\frac{m^2\Delta p^2}{E^2} \lt 0$"

Perkins is very terse throughout the book and I don't see how the second equation is derived. If the electron has an initial energy $E_i$ and looses $\Delta E$ then I get:

${E_f}^2 - \Delta E^2 - ({p_f}^2 - \Delta p^2) = 0$

where

$\Delta E = E_f-E_i$

Expanding the squared terms and simplifying I get $E_f (E_f - 2E_i) - p_f(p_f - 2p_i)=0$. Which isn't right. Can someone clarify how he got this? Also I can intuitively see why the mass portion drops out (rest mass never changes...) but I can't see how he does this mathematically. ($m_f(m_f - 2m_i)=0$??)

Thanks